# Google Auto Complete Places not setting state to empty when Input are cleared

Tags: react-native, react-redux, hybrid-mobile-app

I am using [react-native-google-places-autocomplete](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete) for auto completion of places. I get the result there is no problem in input and getting the Autocomplete searched places.

But, when I click on certain result and then again I clear the `GooglePlacesAutocomplete` input text, the value still remains the previous 
 clicked result item.

Whenever I select a location and I click on `Set Camp` button below is console log.
[image]

Here is other screen shot whenever I clear the input text and again click on button I wish to get console log of undefined or empty string but I get the previous result. Here is screenshot.[image]

Below is the code I am working on:

**SetCampScreen.js**

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
  import { View,
    Text,
    ScrollView,
    TextInput
  } from 'react-native';
  import * as actions from '../../actions';
  import { connect } from 'react-redux';
  import { GooglePlacesAutocomplete } from 'react-native-google-places-autocomplete';

  class SetCampScreen extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
            header: null,
          };
    gotoPatientRegistrationScreen = () => {
      console.log('At Patient Registration method.', this.props.description);

    }
    sendData = (data) => {
      console.log('From send Data: ',data);
      this.props.setLocation(data);
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow : 1, justifyContent : 'center'}}>
            <View style={styles.container}>

              <GooglePlacesAutocomplete
              placeholder="Where are you?"
              minLength={2} // minimum length of text to search
              autoFocus={false}
              returnKeyType={'search'} // Can be left out for default return key https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#returnkeytype
              listViewDisplayed="auto" // true/false/undefined
              fetchDetails={true}
              enablePoweredByContainer={false}
              renderDescription={row => row.description}
              styles={{
              textInputContainer: {
                height: 50,
              },
              textInput: {
                borderRadius: 0,
                marginLeft: 0,
                marginRight: 0,
                marginTop: 0,
                height: 50,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: '#000',
              },
              predefinedPlacesDescription: {
                color: '#1faadb',
              },
              }} // custom description render
              onPress={(data, details = null) => {
              // 'details' is provided when fetchDetails = true
              this.sendData(data);

              }}
              getDefaultValue={() => {
              return ''; // text input default value
              }}
              query={{
              // available options: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete
              key: 'API_KEY',
              language: 'en', // language of the results
              }}

              currentLocation={false} // Will add a 'Current location' button at the top of the predefined places list
              currentLocationLabel="Current location"
              nearbyPlacesAPI="GooglePlacesSearch" // Which API to use: GoogleReverseGeocoding or GooglePlacesSearch
              GoogleReverseGeocodingQuery={{

              }}
              debounce={200}
              />
              <Button
                title="Set Camp"
                onPress={this.gotoPatientRegistrationScreen}
              />
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
      );
    }
  }
  const styles = {
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    textInputStyle: {
      fontSize: 16,
      paddingLeft: 8,
      paddingBottom: 3,
      paddingRight: 8,
      height: 60,
    },
  };
  const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
         description: state.location.locationResponse
       };
  }
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(SetCampScreen);
```

**actions/location_action.js**

```
  import axios from 'axios';
  import { NO_INTERNET, SET_LOCATION } from './types';
  import { NetInfo } from 'react-native';

  export const setLocation = (place) => async dispatch => {
    const { description } = place;
    console.log('Description from setLocation: ',description);
    let netState = await NetInfo.isConnected.fetch();
    console.log('Net state', netState);
    if(!netState) {
      return dispatch({ type: NO_INTERNET });
    }
    try {
      dispatch ({ type: SET_LOCATION, payload: description });
    } catch(exp) {
      console.log(exp);
    }
  };
```

**actions/index.js**

```
export * from './location_action';
```

**actions/types.js**

```
export const NO_INTERNET = 'no_internet';
export const SET_LOCATION = 'set_location';
```

**reducers/location_reducers.js**

```
import { NO_INTERNET, SET_LOCATION } from '../actions/types';

export default function(state = {}, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_LOCATION:
      return { locationResponse: action.payload };

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**reducers/index.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import locationResponse from './location_reducer';

export default combineReducers({
  location: locationResponse,
});
```

I expect whenever I clear the InputText the props value of description should also be cleared. Someone please point me out to achieve this. Thank you.

Comment: you will need a tex chage event of the input. With this way you will be able to store the input state

Comment: GooglePlacesAutocomplete is an external library it doesn't have onTextChange props. @Akis. Any idea ?

Comment: have a look on github, some people had the same issue https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-google-places-autocomplete/issues/236

Comment: @Akis It works, Thank you

Comment: good to hear, you can answer your own question so to help other people with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GooglePlacesAutocomplete` has a `textInputProps` props which accepts an `onChangeText` handler

Usage:

```
textInputProps={{
 onChangeText: (text) => { console.log(text) }
}}
```

Comment: Could you please link to documentation? It is difficult to map this response to something in a Google Maps React library, for example.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this helps clearing both search results and textinput

on Button Clear, add **onPress={()=>{clearSearch();this.textInput.clear() }}**
and give ref to textinput like this, **ref={input => { this.textInput = input }}**

Below is the sample code:

```
<GoogleAutoComplete apiKey={API_KEY} debounce={300} minLength={3 >
        {({ inputValue, handleTextChange, locationResults, fetchDetails, clearSearch ,isSearching
         }) => (
            <React.Fragment>
            <View style={{ marginTop: 80,flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                <TextInput ref={input => { this.textInput = input }} 
                    style={{ height:40,width:300,borderWidth:1,paddingHorizontal:16 }}
                    value={inputValue}
                    onChangeText={handleTextChange}
                    placeholder="Add Address..."
                />
                <Button title="Clear" onPress={()=>{clearSearch();this.textInput.clear() }} />
            </View>
            {isSearching && <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="red" />}
            <ScrollView>
                {locationResults.map((el, i) => (
                <LocationItem
                    props={props}
                    {...el}
                    fetchDetails={fetchDetails}
                    onAutoCompleteInput={this.onAutoCompleteInput}
                    key={String(i)}
                />
                ))}
            </ScrollView>
            </React.Fragment>
        )}
        </GoogleAutoComplete>
```